# Moderncv classic multiline footer text

Tags: header-footer, moderncv

I'd like to add some text in footer using `moderncv classic`with the `/extrainfo` parameter. It was working some time ago, however after some recent changes it has problem with line breaking (it just goes way from the page and does not show the whole content:

[image]

What is the correct way of adding multiline footer text that is also justified? I have had some tries with the `//` however I was not able to justify it properly.

**All the code is from the template** and is available on:
https://www.sharelatex.com/project/587f3511cd715c136762f9f1

Look at lorem ipsum in `\extrainfo`

Comment: Can you give us a minimal working example, i.e. an example that shoewd your behaviour and now does not? It would be ideal if you tell us what versions of `moderncv` you are/were using.

Comment: Hey, I don't have working example, the code I had one year ago was compiling properly and right now I cannot get it working. From what I see every template I get which uses the moderncv classic behaves in same way. I've shared a link that is showing it.

Comment: It's a mandatory clause (and this is the only thing I need in this footer, I don't care about phone/name/github/etc so maybe I can use another mechanism that places footer?). If I'm not able to add it to the footer I'll probably add in on the last page, however it's omitting the problem, rather than solving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reproduce the footer using the following custom setup (add to your preamble):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setfooter}[1][\relax]{%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[C]{\makebox[0pt]{\color{color2}\begin{tabular}[b]{c}
  \ifx#1\relax\else
    \textbf{#1} \\
  \fi
  \@addressstreet
  ~--~%
  \@addresscity
  ~--~%
  \@addresscountry \\
  \mobilephonesymbol \collection@phones@item 
  ~~\textbullet~~%
  \fixedphonesymbol \collection@phones@itemi
  ~~\textbullet~~%
  \faxphonesymbol \collection@phones@itemii \\
  \emailsymbol \@email
  ~~\textbullet~~%
  \homepagesymbol \@homepage \\
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \\ 
  Donec pellentesque faucibus libero, id feugiat nunc volutpat in. \\
\end{tabular}}}
}
\makeatother
```

And now use

```
\makecvtitle
\setfooter
```

As part of your covering letter, use

```
\makelettertitle    
\setfooter[John Doe]
```

If needed, one can expand on the number of symbols added to the footer.

[image]